# Showing Nested Data in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a nested data like this which is passed to blade-

[image]

I want to display it's data in blade view.

So what I have done is-

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu h-ctr h-ctr2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <li class="no-border">
            <label class="pull-left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $category->id }}" checked>
                <strong> {{ $category->name }} (21)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
                @foreach($category->sub_category as $sub_cat)
                    <li>
                        <label class="pull-left">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked value="1"> {{ $sub_cat->name }} (7)
                        </label>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

And I am getting error for nested loop's part-

```
foreach($category->sub_category as $sub_cat)
    <li>
        <label class="pull-left">
            <input type="checkbox" checked value="1"> {{ $sub_cat->name }} (7)
        </label>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

The error is like this-

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Would you please provide errors 1/3 and 2/3?

Comment: 1/3 and 2/3 are same as this error

Comment: Did you make sure `is_array($category->sub_category)` returns true?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access an object property using `->` in an array

Comment: why returning an array? try to use collections

Comment: can we see your model(relation part) code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mate

```
@foreach($category['sub_category'] as $sub_cat)
    <li>
        <label class="pull-left">
            <input type="checkbox" checked value="1"> {{ $sub_cat->name }} (7)
        </label>
    </li>

@endforeach
```

in case this didnt work can you share you controller code too?

**EDIT :** in your controller try to convert the array to a collection (there are simpler why like using eloquent

```
$collection = collect($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@if($category->sub_category)
    @foreach($category->sub_category as $sub_cat)
    <li>
        <label class="pull-left">
            <input type="checkbox" checked value="1"> {{ $sub_cat->name }} (7)
        </label>
    </li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```